Accidentally delete a resource group with NetApp account, Capacity Pool and Volume, chance to restore?
Is it possible to restore a Azure NetApp account / Capacity Pool / Volume if the resources accidentally deleted?
I know that restoring a deleted storage accounts as a resource is possible, is there any chance to do in a similar way for these resources mentoined above?

Try contacting the Azure Support.

@RuiJarimba Unfortunately I do only have the Basic support plan. For technical support i have to upgrade to a paid support plan. For that reason my question is posted here, to see if I miss a already integrated ressources "restore" button.

It is not possible. Refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1642484/is-it-possible-to-recover-an-accidentially-deleted

@Venkatesan Thank you, not possible for ressource group. However I was able to restore storage account that was in this ressource group. Questions is if there is possible to restore for deleted ressources of NetApp Account, Capacity Pool or Volume?

Still, it is not possible refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1193042/netapp-files-backup


Is it possible to restore a Azure NetApp account / Capacity Pool / Volume if the resources accidentally deleted?

According to this MS-Q&A by Sumarigo-MSFT.
It is not possible to restore the Azure NetApp account. Because it does not have support for soft delete for accidental deletion.
Also refer this MS-Document,

When I delete an Azure NetApp Files volume, is the data deleted safely?
Deletion of an Azure NetApp Files volume is performed programmatically
with immediate effect. The delete operation includes deleting keys
used for encrypting data at rest. There is no option for any scenario to recover a deleted volume once the delete operation is executed successfully (via interfaces such as the Azure portal and the API.)

Make sure while creating account set up a backup or snapshot strategy in advance. Also, enable resource locks to the NetApp file resource that prevent either deletions or modifications.
Reference:
Protect your Azure resources with a lock - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Learn
